# how to dynamically size div width to content while keeping it centered and have the contents float left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay I have a div element with multiple children. When the window expands I want the children to fit neatly to the bottom left to the next available space of the grid when there is no longer any room in the div. When the div expands with the window, there is a lot of extra room to the right side of the div that is unnecessary right at the point before it just adds another column. I cant figure out how to center the div while keeping the content floating left and have the div only be as wide as it needs to be for the content.

```
.wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid black 5px;
  margin:10px auto;
}

.wrapper > *{
 margin: 0 auto;
 border:solid black 1px;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

I've tried multiple combos of  having block elements/inline block elements and such to no avail.

I am sorry if I did a very poor job explaining the problem but it might make more sense when you look at the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rfzk5fhx/

Comment: You are saying : and have the div only be as wide as it needs to be for the content, but you only have like 1 image of size left on the right, there is not much flexibility to work with here

Comment: Okay I did a poor job explaining it. Basically if you shrink the size of the window enough. The number of columns will decrease by one and the content will fill in on a new row. If you place the window right at this moment, there will be a lot of left over space to the right of the right most column. I want to figure out how to eliminate this space, and re-center the div if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question correctly but if you want your container div to have width and height resize according to your content, you can do that by setting the display to inline-block and removing the width and height css.

Here is the code:

```
ul {
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rfzk5fhx/2/